# django-avatar combined with django-notification gives an error

Tags: python, django, django-notification

I have installed django-avatar and django-notification (django-avatar uses django-notification, if the latter is installed, in order to send necessary messages to user).

However when I upload/change/delete my avatar I get this error:

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/avatar/change/

Django Version: 1.3
Python Version: 2.6.4
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'grappelli',
 'filebrowser',
 'tinymce',
 'south',
 'avatar',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'notification',
 'tipleaders.main']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Tools\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Tools\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Tools\Python26\lib\site-packages\django_avatar-1.0.5-py2.6.egg\avatar\views.py" in change
  77.             notification.send([request.user], "avatar_updated", {"user": request.user, "avatar": avatar})
File "C:\Tools\Python26\lib\site-packages\django_notification-0.2-py2.6.egg\notification\models.py" in send
  351.             return send_now(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Tools\Python26\lib\site-packages\django_notification-0.2-py2.6.egg\notification\models.py" in send_now
  276.         reverse("notification_notices"),
File "C:\Tools\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  391.             *args, **kwargs)))
File "C:\Tools\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  337.                 "arguments '%s' not found." % (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs))

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /avatar/change/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'notification_notices' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

django-avatar worked neatly just before django-notification was installed.

What went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**URL notification_notices does not exist. Install django-notification urls**, add to urls.py:

```
url('notification/', include('notification.urls')),
```

I recommend that you review your installation of django-notification.

Comment: Thanks. However in the docs of the django-notification there is no install instructions. (https://github.com/jtauber/django-notification/tree/master/docs)